# Python: .copy() for dict

Tags: python

I changed the following

```
sales_gross_last_7_days = self.events_sales_gross_last_7_days_incl_today.get(event.pk, {})
sales_gross_last_7_days.pop(timezone.now().date(), 0)
```

to that one (I added `.copy()`):

```
sales_gross_last_7_days = self.events_sales_gross_last_7_days_incl_today.copy().get(event.pk, {})
sales_gross_last_7_days.pop(timezone.now().date(), 0)
```

Before my change `.pop()` also affected the original dict. Is that normal behaviour for Python?

Comment: Yes, that's normal behavior. If two variable names point to the same object, then changes to the object (if the object is mutable) are visible for both variables, because, well, it's still just one object.

Comment: Dictionaries are mutable objects in Python, like lists. The default behaviour for mutable objects is copy-by-reference.

Comment: Okay, I understand! Does it matter if the `copy()` is before or after the `.get()` in my example?

Comment: @JoeyCoder `.copy()` after the `.get()` might throw an exception, depending on the type returned from your dict.(imagine the get() returns an int for example ...) However, you could use the copy function (import copy from copy) and do `copy(your_dict).get(some_key)`.

Comment: If I do `.copy()` before the `.get()` that would be the "better" way if I understood that correctly? Otherwise, I will go for the second solution you described.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pop() method removes the key that you pass from the dictionary.
Dictionaries are mutable objects, when you use the `pop()` method from this object, you are changing his content.

Comment: Even if I assign that `dict` to a variable first, right?

Comment: OP's question is "Why is this happening?"

Comment: @JoeyCoder I've edit my response to be more clearer. If you assign the dict to another object, when you call the `.pop()` method, you will change the content from the `new object`, and not from the original `dict`.